# LoopBack 2.4: inheriting from User model adds extra columns to mysql table

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I created Admin model based on User:

```
{
  "name": "Admin",
  "plural": "admins",
  "base": "User",
  "strict": true,
  "properties": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "mysql": {
        "dataType": "VARCHAR",
        "dataLength": 50
      }
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "mysql": {
        "dataType": "VARCHAR",
        "dataLength": 60
      }
    },
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Describing Admin table in MySQL db shows extra columns from User model:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email             | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password          | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| realm             | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| username          | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| credentials       | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| challenges        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| emailVerified     | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| verificationToken | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status            | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created           | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastUpdated       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Is there're any way to avoid populating table with some extra props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following code to common/models/admin.js

```
module.exports = function(Admin) {

var excludedProperties = [
  'realm',
  'emailVerified',
  'verificationToken',
  'credentials',
  'challenges',
  'lastUpdated'
];

// Remove the properties from base User model that doesn't have mapped columns
excludedProperties.forEach(function (p) {
  delete Admin.definition.rawProperties[p];
  delete Admin.definition.properties[p];
  delete Admin.prototype[p];
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can directly exclude those properties from the JSON model definition as the strongloop docs says.

`"base": "User",
"properties": {
  "lastUpdated": false,
  "credentials": null,
  "challenges": null,
  "modified": "date"
}`

http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file